# PDF viewer/editor with support for digital signatures that is free

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer, pdf-editor, digital-watermarking

Can anyone recommend a Windows PDF editor/viewer with support for digital signatures that is free? It doesn't have to be any good at editing, just allow signatures without having to pay for a subscription.

Not looking for a trial, but rather a free product. The digital signing needs to accept a mouse drawn signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have personally used [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/) on Windows for PDF editing, signing and submission. Features touted are as follows:

1. Small, Fast, and Feature-Rich PDF Reader
2. Create, View, Annotate, Form Fill, and Sign
3. Integrates with Popular ECMs and Cloud Storage

You can read more on [signing](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/protect-sign-pdf/) or install it and give it a go!

Comment: The free version lets you do digital signatures? I didn't realise that. I will try it out

Comment: I use it, and haven't paid!

Comment: Yep it works! I must have installed the trial last time by mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Online free PDF signing from web browsers is also available at https://web.signer.digital.  Just open your pdf from web browser, draw rectangle where you want to sign and digital signature would be affixed from your local certificate store or cryptographic device like smartcard or usb token.